# How to use COUNT(*) function with distinct values?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

For example I have table that has such columns as `geography` and `children`. I need to count how many there are `childrens` from each `country`.

I only could make such thing:

```
SELECT geography, COUNT( * ) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY children
ORDER BY geography
```

Well, I have for example:

```
Canada John
Canada John
Canada Peter
```

I need result such as from Canada there are 2 `children`.
But If I will make `group by children` there result is:

```
Canada 2
Canada 1
```

If `group by geography` then,

```
Canada 3
```

Comment: What's your problem? What do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to count only the unique values in a group, you can use [`COUNT(DISTINCT expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

```
SELECT geography, COUNT(DISTINCT children) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY geography
ORDER BY geography
```

Comment: sorry, I've just edited it to explain more clearly my question. from the first time it wasn't tht clear.

Comment: It's ok.
To be honest, it still could use some more clarity. But that might just be me.

Comment: well, in the table there columns such as geography and children, the data inside those columns might be repeated several times in the table, for example I have John written twice in the table from Candada and Peter only once, so If I will make group by geography It will say that I have 3 childrens but I have 2 because John is the same person.

Comment: Oh right, now I get it, I updated my answer with what I think you need to achieve this

Answer (score 4):

`SUM` is not really need here. The only thing you will do is to group it by `geography`.

```
SELECT geography, COUNT(DISTINCT children) totalCount
FROM table1
GROUP BY geography
ORDER BY geography
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5454/2)

Answer (score 0):

If geography is country field - you have to add it to group-by.

```
SELECT geography, COUNT(children)
FROM table1
GROUP BY geography
ORDER BY geography
```